# Is there a good implementation of reduction algorithm callable from kernel with dynamic parallelism?

Tags: cuda, reduction

I see reductions algorithms in CUDA (such as summation and maximization over a range of elements) discussed in previous posts, but with dynamic parallelism, they could potentially be implemented in a different way. Is there a more efficient implementation which is callable from inside the kernels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient implementation which is callable from inside the kernels?

[CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html) provides a CUDA reduction primitive compatible with dynamic parallelism, namely, that can be called within kernels.

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: do you also know any library that can calculate multiple k-selection in parallel, for example, 1000000 k-selection in parallel, each is to find the k-largest element among around 10000 elements